# Why doesn't String#match() result contain captured values?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to extract a value from simplest JSON in javascript.

After searching i found `match` to be closest solution.

But trying this with grouping of `RegExp`, it does not give suitable result.

My object is `{"a":"one"}`
and regex i am building is `new RegExp('{"a":"(.*)"}','g')`

my results with

`'{"a":"one"}'.match(new RegExp('{"a":"(.*)"}','g'))` is `["{"a":"one"}"]`

```
'{"a":"one"}'.match(new RegExp('{"a":"(.*)"}'.replace(/([+?^=!:${}|\[\]\/\\])/g, "\\$1"),'g'))
```

is also `["{"a":"one"}"]`

I am expecting the result should have been `["{"a":"one"}", "one"]`

what wrong is happening here?

Comment: Use `JSON.parse('{"a":"one"}').a`

Comment: You are using a global modifier with `String#match`, so all captures are omitted.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew perfect catch..!

Comment: Never use regex on JSON.

Comment: @Bergi i know that, what should be the alternatives ?

Comment: @codeofnode Tushar already posted it - use the builtin JSON parser.

Comment: @Bergi i do not know what my key going to be and i even don't know at which level i would find..

Comment: @codeofnode If the name of the property is dynamic, [use bracket notation](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4244896/1048572), if the object is arbitrarily nested [use recursion](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11922383/1048572). If you don't know how, please [ask a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) with your actual problem. Regex is not a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [`String#match()` reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match):

> If the regular expression includes the `g` flag, the method returns an Array containing all matched substrings rather than match objects. Captured groups are not returned.

Remove `g` modifier to get the expected results.

```js
console.log(
   '{"a":"one"}'.match(/{"a":"(.*)"}/)
);

Or, if you need to get multiple matches, use `RegExp#exec` in a loop or - with the latest JS environments - `String#matchAll`:

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

And the `matchAll` variant:

```js
const s = '{"a":"one","a":"two"}', regex = /"a":"([^"]*)"/g;
const results = Array.from([...s.matchAll(regex)], m => m[1]);
console.log(results);
```