# Google Script: Match RegEx into 2D array

Tags: regex, google-apps-script, multidimensional-array, google-sheets

I'm trying to extract information from Gmail into Google Spreadsheet. The information in the email has a table structure with the following columns List of Products, QTY Sold and the Subtotal for each product. These repeat N times.

When accesing the information using `message.getPlainBody()` I get the following text:

```
Product
Quantity
Price
Chocolate
1
$8.58
Apples
2
$40.40
Bananas
1
$95.99
Candy
1
$4.99
Subtotal:
$149.96
```

**Progress**

First I tried to use a regular expression to identify each row with all his elements:

- Product name: Any amount of characters that don't include ':' (.*)[^:]
- QTY Sold: Any number  \d*
- Anything that looks like a SubTotal [$]\d*.\d*

Wrapping everything up it looks like this

```
    function ExtractDetail(message){
      var mainbody = message.getPlainBody();

     //RegEx
     var itemListRegex = new RegExp(/(.*)[^:][\r\n]+(\d*[\r\n]+[$](\d*\.\d*)[\r\n]+/g);
     var itemList = mainbody.match(itemListRegex);
     Logger.log(itemList);
    }
```

And so far it works:

[image]

> itemList: Chocolate 1 $8.58 ,Apples 2 $40.40 ,Bananas 1 $95.99
>   ,Candy 1 $4.99

However, I'm getting the following result:

- [Chocolate 1 $8.58]
- [Apples 2 $40.40]
- [Bananas 1 $95.99]
- [Candy 1 $4.99]

Instead of:

- [Chocolate] [ 1 ] [$8.58]
- [Apples] [ 2 ] [$40.40]
- [Bananas] [ 1 ] [$95.99]
- [Candy] [ 1 ] [$4.99]

**Question**

My question is, how can I append a new row in a way that it each row corresponds to each match found and that each column corresponds to each property?

How do I turn the result of each match into an array? Is it possible or should I change my approach?

**Update:**

Since the result of my current attemp is a large string I'm trying to find other options. This one poped up:

```
var array = Array.from(mainbody.matchAll(itemListRegex), m => m[1]);
```

Source: [How do you access the matched groups in a JavaScript regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432493/how-do-you-access-the-matched-groups-in-a-javascript-regular-expression)

I'm still working on it. I still need to find how to add more columns and for some reason it starts on 'Apples' (following the examples), leaving 'Chocolates' behind.

Log:

```
Logger.log('array: ' + array);
```

[image]

Comment: If I misunderstood your question, I apologize. Can you confirm whether your script (especially, it's the regex.) in your question is correct, again? I thought that you might have not correctly copied it.

Comment: @Tanaike Hi Tanaike. It is correct, at least it finds what it is asked for. The main issue is to put the info found into a 2D array. I will post an update in a moment.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Your script in your question is correct. Is my understanding correct? And, I think that when you provide the sample values of `itemList` as the text values, it will help users think of the solution. Because in your case, the values are in an image.

Comment: Updated! The script is partially correct. The objective is to take the results from the RegEx and write them down in Sheets as a table. At this point what I can get is just a long string and I'm trying to convert that into a 2D array somehow.

Comment: What Tanaike said was that the regex is invalid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use `matchAll` like `Array.from(mainbody.matchAll(itemListRegex), m => m[1])`, how about this modification?

In this case, `/(.*[^:])[\r\n]+(\d*)[\r\n]+([$]\d*\.\d*)[\r\n]/g` is used as the regex.

#### Modified script:

```
const itemListRegex = /(.*[^:])[\r\n]+(\d*)[\r\n]+([$]\d*\.\d*)[\r\n]/g;
var array = Array.from(mainbody.matchAll(itemListRegex), ([,b,c,d]) => [b,Number(c),d]);
```

#### Result:

```
[
  ["Chocolate",1,"$8.58"],
  ["Apples",2,"$40.40"],
  ["Bananas",1,"$95.99"],
  ["Candy",1,"$4.99"]
]
```

- The result is the same with [TheMaster's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61023439).

#### Test of script:

```js
const mainbody = `
Product
Quantity
Price
Chocolate
1
$8.58
Apples
2
$40.40
Bananas
1
$95.99
Candy
1
$4.99
Subtotal:
$149.96
`;

const itemListRegex = /(.*[^:])[\r\n]+(\d*)[\r\n]+([$]\d*\.\d*)[\r\n]/g;
var array = Array.from(mainbody.matchAll(itemListRegex), ([,b,c,d]) => [b,Number(c),d]);
console.log(array)
```

#### Note:

- About `how can I append a new row in a way that it each row corresponds to each match found and that each column corresponds to each property?`, this means for putting the values to Spreadsheet? If it's so, can you provide a sample result you expect?

#### References:

- [matchAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll)
- [Array.from()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)

Comment: Man I feel I was really close to the answer but everyday we learn something new. Thank you very much for the detailed answer!

Comment: @Luis Alberto Delgado de la Flo Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.

Answer (score 2):

[`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Map) and [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Split) the resulting array by `\n`ew lines:

```js
const data = `Product
Quantity
Price
Chocolate
1
$8.58
Apples
2
$40.40
Bananas
1
$95.99
Candy
1
$4.99
Subtotal:
$149.96`;

const itemListRegex = /.*[^:][\r\n]+\d*[\r\n]+\$\d*\.\d*(?=[\r\n]+)/g;
const itemList = data.match(itemListRegex);

console.info(itemList.map(e => e.split(/\n/)));//map and split
```

Comment: Thank very very much for your answer TheMaster. It also worked for me.